# Full listening node accessibility

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, bitnodes

I have a full listening node running on a linux machine.
Bitcoin Core version 22.0.0
Listening on port 8333

bitcoin-cli -getinfo
{
"version": 220000,
"blocks": 804061,
"headers": 804061,
"verificationprogress": 0.999997863920785,
"timeoffset": 0,
"connections": {
"in": 9,
"out": 10,
"total": 19
},
"proxy": "",
"difficulty": 52391178981379.36,
"chain": "main",
"relayfee": 0.00001000,
"warnings": ""
}

bitcoin-cli -netinfo
Bitcoin Core v22.0.0 - 70016/Satoshi:22.0.0/

```
        ipv4    ipv6   onion   total   block
in         9       0       0       9
out       10       0       0      10       2
total     19       0       0      19
```

Local addresses: n/a

It appears as though the node is able to successfully accept incoming connections from other nodes.
However, if I view the connection status on https://bitnodes.io/ the node is only reachable for ~ 10m and then drops out, despite the fact in the terminal it suggests that I have ongoing in and out connections.

Is there a reason than bitnodes might not report the node as reachable for more than a few minutes?